# Pesquisa em tempo real com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho o seguinte código para fazer um pesquisa em tempo real com jQuery, buscando valores dentro de uma tabela:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".nada").hide();

    var $rows = $('.linhas');
    $('#search').keyup(function () {

        var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
            reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
            text;

        $rows.show().filter(function () {
            text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
            return !reg.test(text);
        }).hide().filter(function () {

            $(".nada").show();

        });

    });

});
```

Porém ocorre um problema: mesmo que retorno apenas um valor igual ao que é digitado, ele cai no `hide()` e mostra o `$('.nada').show()`.

Como posso arrumar isso?

Comment: não sei se te ajuda ou se vc pode usar uma lib jquery para isso mas eu uso essa aqui: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-theme-bootstrap-v4.html

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar esta função passando o valor buscado e onde buscar:

```js
 function busca(value,targetSelector){
        $(targetSelector).show();
        $(targetSelector+':not(:contains("'+ value +'"))').hide();
    }
    

    $('#search').keyup(function () {
       busca($(this).val(), '.linhas');
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Nome</td>
  <td>Sobrenome</td>
</tr>
<tr class="linhas">
  <td>paulo</td>
  <td>guina</td>
</tr>
<tr class="linhas">
  <td>jailson</td>
  <td>mendes</td>
</tr>
<tr class="linhas">
  <td>silas</td>
  <td>malafaia</td>
</tr>
<tr class="linhas">
  <td>marcos</td>
  <td>feliciano</td>
</tr>

</table>
<input id="search" placeholder="buscar">
```

A função vai mostrar tudo e depois esconder o que não contem o texto.

> https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/